# Using JavaTreeProfiler

Tags: java, linux, profiler, jtree

I want to use javaTreeeProfiler to profile my simple java program. I want to use it with 32-bit linux. I downloaded it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcoverage/
The readme file says that "To run the profiler copy the libjprofiler.so to a location that can be found by the dynamic loader." Can anybody tell me what does it mean ? where should I copy that libjrofiler.so file ? I tried to build it. It showed build successfully message but i did not see any call tree. I tried to run it with my simple application but that also did not work. It says :

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
     [java] Could not find agent library jprofiler on the library path, with error: libjprofiler.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
     [java] Java Result: 1
```

Could anybody pl guide me how do I run simple java program with this profiler ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JTreeProfiler is quite old project. Now there is [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html) included in JDK and it has [excellent profiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html) built in.

Comment: It seems that jvisualvm is mainly for memory performance..isn't it ? whereas I am interested in getting call graph view..

Comment: It has both. Also see http://visualvm.java.net/profiler.html
The call graph is available after you take snapshot.

Comment: @ Eugene Kuleshov Thanks...I want to give it a shot ! I tried to use it with Eclipse IDE. For that I  unpacked the zip file in my eclipse folder. (Pl note that i am using lunux). After that when I tried to congifure it in eclipse in run-run Configurations, I selected visual virtual machine launcher. But when I try to run my small java program with this laucher, it doesn't work. It throws error "Internal error occurred during launching !" I am using eclipse Galileo 3.5. Do u have some idea how can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Usually I just launch jvisualvm as a standalone app, then launch other application from IDE or also standalone (can also put a breakpoint on main method in IDE) and then connect jvisualvm to the application vm.